# Is there a way to place values onto a preset sentence and replace them if there is a repeated word?

Tags: python, regex

I have been looking through quite a few functions in order to find a function that will work, but I have had no luck.
I need to create a program that will have an input/preset string variable with a sentence already there. 
I have listed the sentence, so it already has values for each word.

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT CAN YOU DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
listSentence = sentence.split(" ")
```

Ask would have the value 0, Not would have the value 1, What would have the value 2, Your would have the value 3.
And so on...
Ask then is repeated in the 9th position, so I'm wondering how I could make all of the repeated words have the 1st value of them. So the 9th ask, should have the value 0. The 10th word, what would have the value 3, and so on.

Comment: What's the goal here? What output are you trying to get?

Comment: I am trying to get the words, with their new values saved into a txt file.

Comment: @Mureinik: I think it's clear, OP need `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 5, 8, 6, 7, 3, 4]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
d = {}
i = 0
values = []
for i, word in enumerate(sentence.split(" ")):
    if not word in d:
        d[word] = i
    values += [d[word]]
```

Resulting `values` list:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 5, 8, 6, 7, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to preserve the fist index of your words as the key and the real index with words in a list as value :

```
>>> words = sentence.split()
>>> d={}
>>> for i,j in enumerate(words):
...   d.setdefault(words.index(j),[]).append((i,j))
... 
>>> d
{0: [(0, 'ASK'), (9, 'ASK')], 1: [(1, 'NOT')], 2: [(2, 'WHAT'), (10, 'WHAT')], 3: [(3, 'YOUR'), (15, 'YOUR')], 4: [(4, 'COUNTRY'), (16, 'COUNTRY')], 5: [(5, 'CAN'), (11, 'CAN')], 6: [(6, 'DO'), (13, 'DO')], 7: [(7, 'FOR'), (14, 'FOR')], 8: [(8, 'YOU'), (12, 'YOU')]}
>>>
```

And if you want the list of indices you can use a list comprehension like following:

```
>>> [words.index(i) for i in words]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 2, 5, 8, 6, 7, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Yeah, `[words.index(i) for i in words]` is the best way to do this.